# Swift - Possible to programmatically know if function is a @IBAction or framework name?

Tags: swift, reflection

Is it possible to programmatically know if a method is an @IBAction method? - or is it possible to get the framework name of the method being called?

**FUNCTION** only goes so far and doesn't show method attributes.

Do I need to look at reflection to get this information, or is there a quick win?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can:

<kbd>Command</kbd> + click on a method, etc. and it will take you to it's parent declaration.

and

<kbd>Option</kbd> + click will give you the declaration, description, availability, declared in, and reference.